# How to use vite to build esm to commonjs without excluding node modules like stream and path?

Tags: node.js, vite

I want to use vite to pack my esm js to commonjs, but it will clear node modules.
vite.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

const config = defineConfig({
  envDir: process.cwd(),
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: 'index.js',
      formats: ['cjs']
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: '[name].cjs'
      }
    },
    emptyOutDir: true
  }
});

export default config;
```

My example index.js

```js
import Stream from 'node:stream';
console.log(`✨`, `Stream`, Stream);
```

When builded the stream will be an empty object.

How can I prevent node modules from being cleaned up?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it by specifying:

```
build: { ssr: true }
```

Then to eliminate the warning, you should also specify:

```
rollupOptions: {
  input: 'index.js'
}
```